# It is not better to include in Documentation examples from Stack Overflow or create a linking system?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I think it can be more useful to have the documentation to complete all the answers from Stack Overflow, not to replace them. Answers which were improved and viewed by a lot of users are more useful and complex than a quick new example can be.
What you think about this? Should it be permitted to add a new topic without example, if a link is included to a Stack Overflow solved question/problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be ideal.

Most high level SO users can deal without the documentation. It will rarely teach them something new. Noobs, however, such as myself could benefit greatly from reading answers that deal with specific parts of the documentation.

Some of the answers may be inside questions that wouldn't be found unless they were explicitly shown in the section of documentation they belong to.